# From string to an Object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, replace

How can I convert this string: "{one=1,two=2}" into an object with JavaScript? So I can access the values.

I tried replacing the "=" for ":", but then while accessing the object I receive an "undefined". Here is my code:

```
var numbers = "{one=1,two=2}"; //This is how I receive the string

numbers = numbers.replace(/=/g, ':'); //I use the '/g' to replace all the ocurrencies

document.write(numbers.one); //prints undefined
```

Comment: JSON field names must have double quotes around them.

Comment: you are treating string as dictionary/JSON . So numbers.one will be always return undefined. If you want to use in this manner then you should convert string to JSON.

Comment: Where did this string come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the string

```
var str = '{one=1,two=2}';
```

replace `=` character to `:` and also make this as a valid JSON object (needs keys with double-quotes around)

```
var str_for_json = str.replace(/(\w+)=/g, '"$1"=').replace(/=/g, ':');
```

In [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), `\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and the `( )` *capture* what's inside, usable later like here with `$1`

Now parse your string to JSON in order to use like that

```
var str_json = JSON.parse(str_for_json);
```

Now enjoy. Cheers!!

```
document.write(str_json.one);
```

#### FINALLY :

```
var str = '{one=1,two=2}';
var str_for_json = str.replace(/(\w+)=/g, '"$1"=').replace(/=/g, ':');
try {
    var str_json = JSON.parse(str_for_json);   
    document.write(str_json.one);
} catch(e) {
    console.log("Not valid JSON:" + e);
};
```

Comment: It works thank you. Can you explain this part?: (\w+)

Comment: @HillelGarcia : I think you are not fully aware of regex. Have a practice for it. https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/regex/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use regexp to create JSON, I would simply parse the string directly, as in

```
const result = {};

numbers.match(/{(.*?)}/)[1]             // get what's between curlies
  .split(',')                           // split apart key/value pairs
  .map(pair => pair.split('='))         // split pairs into key and value
  .forEach(([key, value]) =>            // for each key and value
    result[key] = value);               // set it in the object
```

Comment: The only ES6 feature here is parameter deconstructing (the `[key, value]` part). If need be, replace that with `forEach(pair => result[pair[0]] = pair[1])`.

Answer (score -1):

1 - a valide JSON is :`var numbers = "{\"one\"=1,\"two\"=2}";` (you need the \")

2- you need to `JSON.parse` the strign

So this works:

```
var numbers = "{\"one\"=1,\"two\"=2}"; //This is how I receive the string
numbers = numbers.replace(/=/g, ':'); //I use the '/g' to replace all the ocurrencies
numbers=JSON.parse(numbers);
document.write(numbers.one); //prints undefined
```

But, it's bad practice !

Comment: So, what is the best practice?
I also dont like it, but it works.

Comment: But he's **not** receiving the string with the property names quoted.